# Restoring Purchases for Non-Consumable Products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am using iOS 10 Messages Extension to build an app. When the user purchase an upgrade to the app I simply add an entry in the UserDefaults. I am working on implementing the "Restore" functionality.

Here is my implementation:

```
private func restorePurchases() {

        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
```

I have the following functions listening for events:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {

        print("paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished")

    }
```

The event restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError is trigged and in the error.localizedDescription it says "Cannot cannot to iTunes Store". I am using iOS 10 and I am running from device. I am already logged in to App Store using iPhone Settings screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you test In-App Purchases, you need to be using a Sandbox Apple ID:

Check out this [documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html)

Testing with a normal Apple ID will not work.

Comment: Yes, I am using Sandbox Apple ID not real ID.